# How do I translate a whole page into another language in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony-2.1

I want to translate a whole html page (text and some markup) including `<p>,<italic>, <strong>` tags in Symfony2. For simple phrases I use `{{ 'read.first'|trans }}` but this does not accept html tags like `<p>`. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't translate complete pages with the Translation component of symfony, that is meaned for just short strings.

Twig always escapes tags in strings, you can read in [the translation docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#twig-templates) how to disable this for your translations:

> Using the translation tags or filters have the same effect, but with one subtle difference: 
>   automatic output escaping is only applied to variables translated using a filter. In other 
>   words, if you need to be sure that your translated variable is not output escaped, you must 
>   apply the raw filter after the translation filter:
>
> ```
> {# text translated between tags is never escaped #}
> {% trans %}
>     <h3>foo</h3>
> {% endtrans %}
>
> {% set message = '<h3>foo</h3>' %}
>
> {# a variable translated via a filter is escaped by default #}
> {{ message|trans|raw }}
>
> {# but static strings are never escaped #}
> {{ '<h3>foo</h3>'|trans }}
> ```